# refactor object into array of key, value objects

Tags: javascript

How do you take a data structure like this -

```
const data = [
  {
    "Country": "Afghanistan",
    "TotalConfirmed": 20917,
    "TotalDeaths": 369,
    "TotalRecovered": 2171,
  },
  {
    "Country": "Albania",
    "TotalConfirmed": 1263,
    "TotalDeaths": 34,
    "TotalRecovered": 945,
  },
  {
    "Country": "Algeria",
    "TotalConfirmed": 10265,
    "TotalDeaths": 715,
    "TotalRecovered": 6799,
  }
];
```

and refactor it into a label/value but exclude one of the keys.

so if you clicked on data[0]

```
const piedata =[
        {
            label: 'TotalConfirmed',
            value: 20917,
        },
        {
            label: 'TotalDeaths',
            value: 369,
        },
        {
            label: 'TotalRecovered',
            value: 2171,
        },
    ];
```

tried this kind of method of mapping the data.

```
const piedata2 = [];
  (data).map((listValue, i) => {      
    console.log("keyxx", listValue);
    console.log("indexxx", i);

    let obj = {"label": "xxx", "value": "xx"};
    piedata2.push(obj);

  })
console.log("piedata2", piedata2);
```

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/buycp9mL/

Comment: that didn't work - https://jsfiddle.net/kyduco6r/ -- you would push the data into the function or the index -- I think just the row data should go into the pie -- so like pieData(data[0])

Comment: I accidentally didn't save the fiddle in time, but I already fixed it. Check my link again and it will work.

Comment: function pieData(row) {
  return Object.entries(row)
  .filter(([key, value]) => Number.isInteger(value))
  .map(([label, value]) => ({ label, value }));
}


const piedata = pieData(data[0])

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kyduco6r/1/  -- more like this

Comment: I told you I accidentally saved an unfinished version; you looked at it before I was able to fix it. My code has been fixed and working for at least 5 minutes now; check the link in my first comment. You seem to have working code now, so rather than comment on other answers with code you nicked from me, how about we all move on? :)

Comment: @ChrisG you have have to give he the updated url.

Comment: @dabishan No I don't, jsfiddle has a "Set as base" button. Kindly check the updated & working fiddle linked to in my first comment before telling me how posting a fiddle works :)

Comment: @ChrisG my bad! You learn new things everyday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I could think of:

```
const pieData = (row) => {
    return Object.keys(row)
        .filter(x => x !== 'Country')
        .map(key => ({label: key, value: row[key]}));
}
```

It is working here: https://jsfiddle.net/paeorbs6/

Comment: Could you check the jsfiddle. My solution seems to work

Answer (score 0):

you can use `for-in` statement like this :

```
const piedata2 = [];
for(var i in data[0]) {
   if(i !== "Country") }
      piedata2.push({label : i , value: data[0][i]})
   }
}
console.log("piedata2", piedata2);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kyduco6r/  -- what about this method - although it didn't seem to work

Comment: 'i' is not defined  no-undef